# Fetch in React app - how to work with opaque response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I am very new to react and JS, trying to get data from the service in my React component, but nothing comes in:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:9000/someEndPoint", 
    {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      cache: "no-cache",
      headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }

        return response.json();
    })
    .then((b) => {

      console.log(b);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Update: I am getting an opaque response due to no-cors mode, any idea how can I deal with this?

Comment: So how do you know the response is rejected? (i.e. "please add more information to your post". You make a claim about what the code is doing, show the evidence that makes you think that is the case, so others don't need to guess). On a completely different note, if you have a single argument, arrow notation doesn't need the additional parentheses, making things a little easier to read.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` or something else/another boilerplate? You may have to ensure that your server is proxied properly in your webpack file, and your package.json.

Comment: I do use create-react-app

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in VS Code, I see in the watch that response is rejected

Comment: I had to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:[port]"` to my `package.json` when I used Express with my CRA app. And `proxy: { '/api': 'http://localhost:[port]'},` to my `devServer` object in the webpack JS.

Comment: try to add at first then() a second argument, with the failure call... the promise only call the first then with two arguments (if success argument, if fail argument)

Comment: So, as I am using no-cors mode, I am getting an opaque response, which I can't read. Any idea how can I deal with that?